# Words which mean: "second largest", "second smallest"

Tags: single-word-requests

English has the word *penultimate* meaning "second to last". Are there similar words for size, as in "second largest" and "second smallest"?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: noooooo.

Comment: Looking at this, I found some interesting words - 'antepenultimate' (third from last) 'preantepenultimate' (fourth from last) and a possible 'suprapreantepenultimate' (fifth from last). But nothing for large and small, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used "next to."  Kevin said, "I'm next to the tallest person in my class."  I hate "second to."  It sounds as if something is two away from the other item.  I realize the term is common, but it's not what I grew up with.